# What does indemnity mean in a "Historique Espèces" (~= history of cash operations) of a securities account in a French financial institution?

Tags: stocks, loans, france

I am reading in a "Historique Espèces" (~= history of cash operations) spreadsheet of a securities account in a French financial institution, namely [Fortuneo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuneo). It says:

[image]

I'm quite confident that indemn.=indemnity but I don't know why there are some indemnities in the spreadsheet.

What does indemnity  mean in a "Historique Espèces" (~= history of cash operations) spreadsheet of a securities account in a French financial institution?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/ppbWZJ